# Can I ignore tap event on a Textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, textbox, event-handling

Ive created a custom Path shape for my application. I add this shape to my canvas and I also add a Textbox centered inside this shape.

Tapping the shape and hitting the text triggers the tap event on the Textbox, is there a way I can disable that?

I want every tap on my shape to go to the shape, not the Textbox that lies ontop of that shape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some options.

`IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the `TextBox` will ignore your tap events, but then you won't get tap if they only hit it...

You can edit the Control Template for a `TextBox` and add your `Path` shape to it directly as part of the Template, so it all accepts the Event as a TextBox.

You could intercept the Event all together by adding a layer over both the objects, something like;

```
<Grid>
  <Path/>
  <TextBlock/>
  <Rectangle/><!-- Use to intercept the event over the whole thing -->
</Grid>
```

Or you could even just make that stuff its own object by embedding as `UserControl` and accept it all together that way.

Just depends what you're trying to do. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display text, but without the ability to edit it, why don't you use `TextBlock` instead?